# Bundled files and cache busting, lazy loading

Tags: caching, ionic-framework, ionic2

Looking for an elegant solution for forcing cache buster.

Right now, I get troubles when bundled files (main.js, vendor.js & co) get an update.
One simple solution may be to enable:

- On build, versioning of file, i.e. appending a unique string to filenames, e.g. `main.9d20886f478d1f484d41ec3d3f7119d5.js`
- Changing reference in `index.html` file
  but seems however that there may be issues while lazy loading
  I know that some other frameworks have plugins that enable this (.e.g [Laravel mix versioning](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/3) [3:14] )

Anything existing, any thought?

Cheers